# Error in function using numeric vector

Tags: r

Create a function that takes in a numeric vector. The objective is to forecast using exponential smoothing.

The formula is ( is the actual value and ̂ is the forecasted value) - ̂+1=̂+(− ̂)

The output of the function should be a data frame with two columns – actual and predicted values. Set a default value of 0.8 for .

```
a1 <- c(1.02, 2.21, 2.35, 3.06, 4.4, 5.2)
f1 <- c(1.05, 2.3, 3.0, 2.96, 4.1, 5.5)
alpha <- 0.8
f2 <- f1 + alpha * (a1 - f1)
```

I don't think I need a function to solve this problem. I am a rookie in R, I appreciate if anyone can let me know anything wrong in my thought.

BTW, if I'm trying to use function to solve it,

```
ExpForecast = function(v,alpha = 0.8)
{
   ResultMatrics1 = data.frame()
   for (i in 2:length(v))
   {

       a = data.frame(v[i],(ResultMatrics1[(i-1),2]))
                         +alpha*(v[(i-1)]-ResultMatrics1[(i-1),2])
       ResultMatrics1 = rbind(ResultMatrics1,a)
   }
   return (ResultMatrics1)
   colnames(ResultMatrics1) = c("y","y_hat")
}

ExpForecast(v=c(2,5,13,24,53))
```

There always an error prompt out.